# Fixed height parent should include absolute / fixed positioned child

Tags: html, css, position

I am referring `div.settings` as the "parent" and `#mainMenu` as the "child".

Now, I want to create a dropdown similar to one in Windows. So, the height of the parent needs to be **fixed** (as it was initially). Also, I want my child to be `fixed` positioned to be able to create the below effect (I will create the effect myself later on).

[image]

This is what I have done so far.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: default;
  user-select: none;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.settings {
  padding: 7px 16px;
  border: 0.5px solid #7777;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

#mainMenu {
  position: fixed;
  /* or absolute */
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: stretch;
}

span.opt {
  padding: 5px 20px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin: 0;
  background: #777;
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
}

span.selected {
  display: inline-block !important;
  background: #28F;
}

#mainMenu:hover>span.opt {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class='settings'>
  <p>Select default browser</p>
  <span id='mainMenu'>
    <span class='opt'>Google Chrome</span>
    <span class='opt'>Mozilla Firefox</span>
    <span class='opt'>Safari</span>
    <span class='opt selected'>Microsoft Edge</span>
    <span class='opt'>Opera</span>
    <span class='opt'>Internet Explorer</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

### **Problem**

The fixed positioned child is overflowing from the body of its parent.

I want the parent to **include** the menu inside its content. Something like in the below picture:

[image]

The red line (roughly) indicates that where the border of the parent should be.

**Note**: Only CSS (because nothing is dynamic without the effect), and I have displayed only one of the menu in my code (to minimise complexity and code length). In reality, there could be *many*.

In short, I just want the child to remain fixed-positioned and inside the body of the parent with fixed height.

Comment: What do you mean by you want the child element to be fixed inside the parent?

Comment: it's not possible to make an element with dynamic height if his content has `position: fixed` only if you used javascript. check my answer to see if that behavior is what you are looking for

Comment: @Daniel I want the child shouldn't *overflow* out of the parent's body. And the former should be `fixed` or `absolute` positioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap your menus in a div with a min-height to hold that space in the parent div, **or** use a "placeholder" span.opt.selected with visibility: hidden (see updated snippet).

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: default;
  user-select: none;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.settings {
  padding: 7px 16px;
  border: 0.5px solid #7777;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: inherit;
}

#mainMenu {
  position: fixed;
  /* or absolute */
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: stretch;
}

span.opt {
  padding: 5px 12px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin: 0;
  background: #777;
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
}

span.placeholder {
  visibility: hidden;
}

span.selected {
  display: inline-block !important;
  background: #28F;
}

#mainMenu:hover>span.opt {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class='settings'>
  <p>Select default browser</p>
  <span id='mainMenu'>
    <span class='opt'>Google Chrome</span>
    <span class='opt'>Mozilla Firefox</span>
    <span class='opt'>Safari</span>
    <span class='opt selected'>Microsoft Edge</span>
    <span class='opt'>Opera</span>
    <span class='opt'>Internet Explorer</span>
  </span>
  <span class='opt selected placeholder'>placeholder</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Cool. But still I am looking for a way to prevent writing `min-height: 2em;` by myself. I mean, let the browser do the measurement by itself. is it possible anyway?

Comment: Thanks a lot! this is what I was looking for

Answer (score 2):

I added a hover effect so that you can see that .setting height is dynamic

```js
var mainMenu = document.getElementById("mainMenu");
var heightc = document.getElementById("heightc");
var opt = document.getElementsByClassName("opt");
var scrollHeight = 0;
mainMenu.addEventListener('mouseenter', function(){
    for(var i=0; i<opt.length; i++){
       if(opt[i].className.indexOf("selected") > 0){
          var dm = i*opt[i].offsetHeight;
          mainMenu.style.bottom = dm + 'px';
          heightc.style.paddingBottom = dm + 'px';
          scrollHeight = window.scrollY;
          window.scrollTo(0, window.scrollY+dm);
       }
    }
});


mainMenu.addEventListener('mouseleave', function(){
    mainMenu.style.bottom = 0;
    heightc.style.paddingBottom = 0;
    window.scrollTo(0, scrollHeight); 
});
```

```css
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 cursor: default;
 user-select: none;
 font-family: Roboto;
 font-weight: 400;
}
#fs{
  height: 1000px;
}
.settings {
 padding: 7px 16px;
 border: 0.5px solid #7777;
 border-radius: 4px;
}
#mainMenu {
 display: inline-flex;
 flex-flow: column wrap;
 justify-content: flex-start;
 align-items: stretch;
  position: relative;
}
/* added */
#mainMenu span{
  display: none;
}
#mainMenu .selected{
  display: block;
}
#mainMenu:hover .opt{
  display: block;
}
/* end added */
span.opt {
 padding: 5px 12px;
 flex-grow: 1;
 margin: 0;
 background: #777;
 color: #FFF;
 text-align: center;
}
span.selected {
 display: inline-block !important;
 background: #28F;
}
```

```html
<div class='settings'>
  <p id="heightc">Select default browser</p>
  <span id='mainMenu'>
    <span class='opt'>Google Chrome</span>
    <span class='opt'>Mozilla Firefox</span>
    <span class='opt'>Safari</span>
    <span class='opt selected'>Microsoft Edge</span>
    <span class='opt'>Opera</span>
    <span class='opt'>Internet Explorer</span>
  </span>
</div>
<div id="fs"></div>
```

Comment: Nice, it's almost done. Just a minor issue that fixed content wouldn't scroll with page when I will add multiple parents.

Comment: @rv7 delete the `fs` div and its style `#fs` I just I added it to so that you can test page scrolling

Comment: the current solution works good. But, for the **effect** (in the gif), the child needs to be `absolute` or `fixed` positioned. The reason why I am saying this is, I will **translate the menu** along the vertical through JavaScript using top and bottom properties which will not work as long as the child's position is `static` or `relative`. Hope you understand my thoughts

Comment: @rv7 what about now? there is just a little problem I don't know if it will bother you

Comment: The page translation isn't there in the effect. I want the child to translate. Meanwhile, you were working, I also tried to do something on [the effect](https://www.dropbox.com/s/re2l5ve46phn0lg/20181001_154436%20%281%29.mp4?raw=1)

Comment: @rv7 I have already done what you have done but the problem is that the `Select default browser` got hidden

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181076/discussion-between-rv7-and-evgeni-fotia).

Answer (score 1):

> I want the parent to include the menu inside its content

Adding position `absolute` or `fixed` to the menu takes it out of the content flow, so you won't get the layout you want without restructuring the HTML a little.

Demo added below, let me know if you have any questions. You will need to add additional logic to check if menu is out of viewport bounds.

```js
const MENU = document.getElementById('mainMenu');
const SELECTION = document.getElementById('selection');
const OPTION_CONTAINER = document.getElementById('options');
const OPTIONS = [...document.querySelectorAll('.opt')];

let height;

function addEventListeners() {
  OPTIONS.forEach((option, index) => {
    option.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      let val = option.innerText;
      SELECTION.innerText = val;
      positionMenu(index);

      if (MENU.classList.contains('is-open')) {
        MENU.classList.remove('is-open')
      }
    })
  })

  MENU.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
    MENU.classList.add('is-open');
  })

  MENU.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
    MENU.classList.remove('is-open');
  })
}

function getOptionHeight() {
  height = OPTIONS[0].getBoundingClientRect().height;
}

function positionMenu(index) {
  index--;
  OPTION_CONTAINER.style.transform = `translateY(-${index * height}px)`;
}

getOptionHeight();
addEventListeners();
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: default;
  user-select: none;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.settings {
  /* demo */
  margin: 100px 0 100px;
  
  padding: 7px 16px;
  border: 0.5px solid #7777;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.options-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
}

.options {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: stretch;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.opt {
  padding: 5px 20px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin: 0;
  background: #777;
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

.selected {
  background: #28F;
}

.options-container.is-open .options {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.opt:hover {
  background: #28F;
}
```

```html
<div class='settings'>
  <p>Select default browser</p>
  <div id='mainMenu' class="options-container">
    <span id="selection" class="opt selected">Select</span>
    <div class="options" id="options">
      <span class='opt'>Google Chrome</span>
      <span class='opt'>Mozilla Firefox</span>
      <span class='opt'>Safari</span>
      <span class='opt'>Microsoft Edge</span>
      <span class='opt'>Opera</span>
      <span class='opt'>Internet Explorer</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: +1 for your effort. But, I was expecting the use of CSS. Could it be done using some nesting of elements?

Comment: You could use the HTML in the snippet and replace mouseover with css hover.

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript and CSS Solution Proposal

In order to **take controls on positioning** should be good to keep the options and the selected option in two **different contexts** and then operate on the **top property** of the option **programmatically**. 
After that, you have to tackle the **dynamic changes of the top property** and the value **getting** and **setting** in the markup.

```js
function setTop() {
  let height = document.querySelector(".opt").clientHeight;
  document.querySelector(".options").style.top = height * 3 * (-1) + "px";
}
setTop();
```

```css
* {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      cursor: default;
      user-select: none;
      font-family: Roboto;
      font-weight: 400;
    }

    .settings {
      padding: 7px 16px;
      border: 0.5px solid #7777;
      border-radius: 4px;
    }

    #mainMenu {
      position: relative;
      display: block;
      width:300px;
    }
    #mainMenu .options {
      position: absolute;
      display: none;
      width:100%;
    }
    #mainMenu:hover .options {
      display: block;
    }

    #mainMenu .opt {
      padding: 5px 20px;
      background: #777;
      color: #FFF;
      text-align: center;
    }
    #mainMenu .opt.selected {
      background: #28F;
    }
    #mainMenu .selection {
      display:block;
    }
```

```html
<div class='settings'>
      <p>Select default browser</p>
      <div id='mainMenu'>
        <span class='opt selected selection'>Microsoft Edge</span>
        <div class='options' style="top:0;">
          <div class='opt'>Google Chrome</div>
          <div class='opt'>Mozilla Firefox</div>
          <div class='opt'>Safari</div>
          <div class='opt selected'>Microsoft Edge</div>
          <div class='opt'>Opera</div>
          <div class='opt'>Internet Explorer</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```